# How to Integrate Velocity with Log4j2?

Tags: java, velocity, log4j2

I have a web application that was using Log4j and Velocity v1.7

This is how I had integrated Log4j and Velocity 1.7

```
private static VelocityEngine velocityEngine = new VelocityEngine();

static {
    velocityEngine.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RUNTIME_LOG_LOGSYSTEM_CLASS,
            "org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute");
    velocityEngine.setProperty("runtime.log.logsystem.log4j.LOGGER",
            VelocityUtil.class.getName());
    velocityEngine.init();
}
```

But after upgrading the application to LOG4j2, I am getting following exception...

```
  java.io.FileNotFoundException: velocity.log (Permission denied)
```

This is the same exception which made me configured the VelocityEngine's property in the static block above, when I was using LOG4J.

Apparently, there is no equivalent of Log4JLogChute that is compatible with Log4j2.

Does anyone know how to achieve compatibility between Log4j2 and Velocity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you replace the log4j 1.x jar with the log4j-1.2-api jar it should start working.

Comment: I do not have log4j 1.x anywhere in my project. Also, I added log4j-1.2-api version 2.7 in my application. I started receiving linkage errors.

Comment: You may not have specified it but Velocity uses it. You have to satisfy that dependency.  If you are using Maven you can run "mvn dependency:tree" and see if the log4j 1.x jar is present. If it is, you need to exclude it from the dependency that is causing it to be included. If it is not there then just add the log4j-1.2-api jar.

Comment: Here is the exception details: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.<init>(Lorg/apache/log4j/Layout;Ljava/lang/String;Z)V" the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader) of the current class, org/apache/velocity/runtime/log/Log4JLogChute, and the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/StandardClassLoader) for the method's defining class, org/apache/log4j/RollingFileAppender, have different Class objects for the type org/apache/log4j/Layout used in the signature

Comment: I have no log4j 1.x present.                                                           [INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-web:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-jcl:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.7:compile  I have not log4j 1.x present

Comment: I suspect that log4j-1.2-api is conflicting with log4j-api jar ?

Comment: No. log4j-1.2-api provides the Log4j 1.x api to applications that have not converted to Log4j 2.  Can you try changing "runtime.log.logsystem.log4j.LOGGER" to "runtime.log.logsystem.log4j.logger"?

Comment: Yeah, I just noted that I had it incorrect. I will try... This is taking time because this is happening only in deployment environment and that is having its own complex nuances... Please bear with me. I am hopeful it will work. Meanwhile, I also tried using CommonsLogChute and the app worked fine, but I am yet to test the logging with that Chute.

Comment: It worked. That was the issue I was getting Linkage errors.